# React - using Context to pass down array variable, but when there is an update, component receiving array variable not re-render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, use-state, use-context

I am using `Context` to pass down the `exerciseList` array variable to 2 different components,

`ExerciseList` component and `Exercise` component.

`Exercise` component renders individual exercises and then
`ExerciseList` component import that and implement it.

But the issue now is that when there is an update,
t.ex exercise has been deleted, so `ExerciseList` should re-render.

But it won't happen unless I refresh the page.

This is my `Context`,

```
function ContextProvider(props) {
    const [ exerciseList, setExerciseList ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/')
            .then(response => {
                setExerciseList(response.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{exerciseList,
                                  setExerciseList,
                                }}>
            {props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export { Context, ContextProvider }
```

and I am receiving the `exerciseList` in `ExerciseList` component like this

```
export default function ExerciseList(){
    const { exerciseList } = useContext(Context)

    const exerciseData = exerciseList.map( exercise => (
        <Exercise key={exercise._id} 
                  id={exercise._id}
                  username={exercise.username} 
                  description={exercise.description} 
                  duration={exercise.duration}
                  date={exercise.date}
        />
    ))

    return(
        <div>
            <h3>Exercise List</h3>
            <table className="exercise-table"> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {exerciseData}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the `Exercise` component where I have `delete` function is like this

```
export default function Exercise({id, username, description, duration, date}) {
    const { setExerciseList } = useContext(Context)

    const deleteExercise = (id) => {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/exercises/' + id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        setExerciseList(exercises => exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id))    
    }

    return (
        <tr>
           <td>{username}</td>
           <td>{description}</td>
           <td>{duration}</td>
           <td>{date}</td>
           <td>
                <Link to={"/edit/" + id}>edit</Link> | <button onClick={() => deleteExercise(id)}>delete</button>
           </td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

I wonder why? I put the `console.log(exerciseList.length > 0)` in ExerciseList component,
to see if its catching the change of the array, and it does not.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put `console.log(exerciseList.length > 0)` in ExerciseList? If you put it above `exerciseList.map` then you should see some log.

---

Here might be a problem that you met.

`setState` from `useState` is not the same as `this.setState` in class component.

It does not accept a function as a parameter.

So `setExerciseList` should be like this

```js
    const deleteExercise = (id) => {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/exercises/' + id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        // setExerciseList(exercises => exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id))  
        setExerciseList(exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id))    
    }
```

**Note:** you should ensure that `axios.delete` performs properly before deleting the item in UI. For example, move the `setExerciseList` to be inside `.then` callback and give it some updating state.

Comment: Thanks! I create an extra boolean state to check if it should get an updated DB and rerender as well. I realise I need to 'get' the updated DB from the mongoDB, and also the condition I gave 'if(response.data.leangth > 0)' was blocking ExerciseList from re-rendering. But the solution I have now, does not alter the array state based on id anymore but feeding the updated data instead. What would be the main difference between feeding updated data to alter the array || alter array by filter based on id?